# how to ensure binding to hashChange event does not bubble?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-bubbling

I'm trying to keep my hashChange event binding from bubbling.

I have this:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function( e ) {
    console.log("hash fired");
    // run hashChange routine
    });
```

My script manages panels on a page with each panel having it's own history-stack. The above fires with every transition, but I'm blocking the hashChange on forward transitions, so I can navigate deeper into the panel. On backwards "transitions", only hashChange fires and is not blocked, so I can go back up.

A navigation might look like this:

```
panel A, start down > page2
panel A, page2 down > page3
panel A, page3 up > page2
panel A, page2 up > start - hashChange fires twice here...
```

All works well (= hashChange fires once), until I reach the page before initial setup. On the final step the above hashChange-binding fires twice. I have tried forever to set a flag somewhere to block the 2nd hashChange, but it doesn't work as I had hoped.

**Question:**
How can ensure this does not bubble? I'm trying something like this, but it's not working:

```
var $blockBubblingHashes = 0;
$(window).bind('hashchange', function( e ) {       
   if ($blockBubblingHashes == 0) {
      // run hashChange routine
      $blockBubblingHashes = 1; 
      } else {
         $blockBubblingHashes = 0;
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the event handler to fire only once, you should consider using the [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one) function, which removes the handler after it's first execution.

```
$(window).one('hashchange', function( e ) {    
    console.log("hash fired");
    // run hashChange routine
});
```

If you specifically want to stop the event bubbling, rather than removing the handler, you should checkout the [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) and [`stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) on methods the event object. Unfortunately, I get the impression you're binding all your `hashchange` handlers to the `window`, and jQuery does not document in which order event handlers bound to the same element are executed; so you'll have no reliable way of knowing which handler is invoked first.

Comment: @frequent: if you're binding all your `hashchange`'s to `window`, you'll have to use `stopImmediatePropagation()`, but "*jQuery does not document in which order event handlers bound to the same element are executed; so you'll have no reliable way of knowing which handler is invoked first.*"

Comment: tried binding to one() and both "propgrations", all result in only a single event being fired after which the function goes silent. Doesn't help. Because I need it to fire "once per hashChange"

Comment: @frequent: I'm not entirely sure what your after, so hopefully someone else can help you :).

Comment: ok. thanks for pointing me in some new directions. I'll figure someting out.

Comment: Found it. An error in my transitioning function triggered another hashChange event. I'm giving you the answer, because you all your points are valid. Thx again.